# What is a translation of "All can be given, all can be taken" to assist with a tattoo design. Thank you!

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Just as the title says, seeking a possible translation to the phrase. Any and all help is appreciated and thank you to those who are linguistically talented unlike myself! Yall take care!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what it means in English. To get a good translation of a motto it is necessary to unpack its exact meaning and implications in the original language and then, using that knowledge, to pack it up in Latin. Translating the “packed” version literally word for word without unpacking never really works.

Answer (score 2):

Omnia dari possunt; possunt tolli omnia.

Answer (score 1):

From Cicero, Phillipics fragments:

*Cara est cuiquam salus quam aut dare aut eripere potest Antonius?* ("Does anyone hold dear safety that can be given or snatched away by Antony?")

Hence, in your case it is:

*Cuncta aut dari aut eripi possunt.*

Note that when typically talking about Everything collectively as a thing in itself, often the word cuncta is used rather than *omnia*, which tends to mean in all respects or all things. For example:

*officia cuncta, pudor, honor, constantia in hoc...* ("All virtues, modesty, honor, fortitude, are in this") Ausonius

Of course, omnia can be used also. For example:

*omnia enim vera in praeteritis necessaria sunt* ("All things which were true in the past are necessary.") Cicero, *De Fato*